# Will electron-builder use dependencies that it doesn't need

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I have been wondering this for a while and i haven't found a specific answer.

I am building a whole app using **`Electron`** and **`React`** to make the ui.

My question is if i should have a 2 complete different source code for each part of the app (**`electron`** and **`react`**) because i don't know very wekk how the package **`electron-builder`** works.

To be precise, since i have installed **`react`** (and **`react`** packages related) and some others that i just use for the ui part, when i build the app for distribution, will **`electron`** include the dependencies that doesn't require? Making the final bundle **bigger**!

Answer (score 0):

While `electron-builder` has [configuration options](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents) to specify which files are to be included, it is not a replacement for a tool like `webpack`.

`electron-builder` creates the installer/target artefact for your platform and packs the files you have specified.

It does not sift through your `node_modules` via tree shaking to create a minified script that only contains the code you need.

You can compare it a with the `files` array in the `package.json` that tells `npm pack` which files should be put into the tarball.

In the default configuration (and I don't know if you can overwrite that, but it is surely worth a try by setting specific node modules to ignore) it will include the entire production dependencies.

Another solution than manually ignoring the react dependencies would be to hold your react app in its own directory in your project and only include the build artefact.

```
gui/
 |_build/
     |_your built stuff
 |_your react stuff
 |_node_modules
 |_package.json
main.js
node_modules
package.json
```

In this case you would configure `electron-builder` to include `main.js` and `gui/build`. With this `electron-builder` should only include the production dependencies of the outer project.